# How to send javascript array to a rest service

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have a javascript array that holds a couple of ids. I want to send it to a rest webservice that I have written. Here is the code that I have for that -

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:portNo/GlassdoorWebProject/index/getJobsData/list/',
        crossDomain : true,
        data : JSON.stringify(allIds),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success : function(data){
            alert("success in call2");

        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
          alert("error"); 


        }
    });
```

When I execute this code I am getting an alert box that says error. This is how the method in my web service looks like -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getJobsData/list/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<JobDetails> getJobs(@PathVariable("ids") String jobIds) {
    System.out.println("ids"+jobIds);
    return jobService.getJobDataForIds(jobIds);
}
```

When I run the it in a browser with the url in the browser it works. But when I run it through the code it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the error? And generally you should POST not GET to send data back to the server

Comment: You can't send it as data. You need to append `allIds` to the url.

Comment: Other than using a `GET` instead of a `POST` or `PUT`, the code fragment looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getJobsData/list/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<JobDetails> getJobs(@RequestParam("ids") String jobIds) {
    System.out.println("ids"+jobIds);
    return jobService.getJobDataForIds(jobIds);
}
```

the main problem is that you are sending the ids as the request parameters, but your are looking the values from the url. So i changed the code of your web service and i think it will solve your problem.